# Restart Flash application, not always working

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I have a Main.mxml that has this:

```
  <components:ScreenSaver id="ScreenSaver" />
```

This component is another .mxml

Basically, when this screensaver object is visible, and playing videos, I want to allow this for a set amount of time, then, I want the entire application to drop, and restart.  So,  I put an event listener in Main.mxml:

```
addEventListener(AppConstants.REBOOT, p_Reboot);
```

p_Reboot is:

```
    public function p_Reboot( e:Event = null):void
    {                                       
             var mgr:ProductManager = new ProductManager("airappinstaller");                mgr.launch("-launch "+ topApplication.nativeApplication.applicationID + " " + topApplication.nativeApplication.publisherID);
             topApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }   

Then, in ScreenSaver at the critical moment, I do this:
    dispatchEvent(new Event(AppConstants.REBOOT, true));
```

Everything seems to work perfectly, the listener works, it get to the `p_Reboot` function, the application exits,  but it never starts back up.

However, If I call `p_Reboot` from a button click within main.mxml, it works.  Is the problem that my dispatch event is being done in ScreenSaver.mxml, which is in a different application domain?  So it can't find the application to restart?

Any help would be greatly apprieciated.